# ICU Probe All Currency Symbols

Tags: c++, unicode, dictionary, icu

Is there a way to probe the [ICU library](http://site.icu-project.org/) for all [UChar's](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/umachine_8h.html#a7213b402d772584553f6e614109e6e4) representing currency symbols supported by the library?

My current solution is iterating through all locales and for each locale, doing something like this:

```
const DecimalFormatSymbols *formatSymbols = formatter->getDecimalFormatSymbols();
UnicodeString currencySymbol = formatSymbols->getSymbol(DecimalFormatSymbols::kCurrencySymbol);
```

Then saving off each UChar in currencySymbol into a map (so no duplicates).

Comment: concurrency and currency are not the same :)

Comment: Are you looking for every possible UChar that could be in every possible currency in every possible locale? Long or short form of the symbol?  Your code above will only consider the default currency for that locale, for example. (By the way, you might want to use UnicodeSet in there somewhere)

Comment: I'm only concerned withthe short form default for the locales. I'm not familiar with UnicodeSet but I'm looking into now. Thank you.

Comment: @Travis May I ask what the application is for?

Comment: @Steven - Pet project for currency conversion. Windows for now, maybe Mac later. I see your an ICU contributer? I have a question / feature request for the MessageFormat class. Do you have an email I can hit you at?

Comment: @Travis - I am, but better to just file a bug. That hits harder!

Comment: @Travis - added some contact info to https://ssl.icu-project.org/trac/wiki/Srl#Courriel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All currency symbols have the category Sc (Symbol, Currency), so you can just enumerate all characters from that category.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <icu/unicode/uchar.h>

UBool print_all_currency_symbols(const void* context, UChar32 start, UChar32 limit, UCharCategory type) {
    if (type == U_CURRENCY_SYMBOL) {
        for (UChar32 c = start; c < limit; ++ c)
            printf("%04x\n", c);
    }
    return TRUE;
}

int main() {
    u_enumCharTypes(print_all_currency_symbols, NULL);

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more? I'm not familiar with "category" as it applies to UnicodeStrings or the Locales.

Comment: This looks great. I had no idea helper functions like the u_enumCharTypes() existed. I'll play with this. Thank you.

Comment: That API is an interesting one. You can use it to set something in your 'context' variable, and so use it as a callback.   You could collect these UChar32s into a UnicodeSet for quick membership testing. Also, this solution will get the Unicode 'currency symbol' chars, but will NOT get the chars actually used for currency symbols, such as "$" or "Rs." etc.

Comment: @Steven: The `$` character *is* in the [Sc category](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Sc/list.htm). You are right about `Rs.` though as it is not a single character.

Comment: @KennyTM - you are right about $, I stand corrected. Not "Lm", "SFr", "N$" (the N part) or "USD" though, as well.

Comment: If I'm using this handler to populate a UnicodeSet of all currency symbols (instead of just printing them). How do I know when the enumeration is complete?

Comment: @Travis: It completes when the `u_enumCharTypes` function completes.

Comment: @KennyTM thank you! I didn't realize u_enumCharTypes blocked until it was done. Thank you very much